# issue with java late binding and method overload

Tags: java

I am just starting out with Java and came cross this code snippet:

```
class Employee {
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        System.out.println("Employee.setSalary():" + salary);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee ken = new Manager();
        int salary = 200;
        ken.setSalary(salary);  // *

    }

}

class Manager extends Employee {
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        System.out.println("Manager.setSalary():" + salary);
    }
}
```

According to my understanding of java late binding rule, the line on `*` should invoke the `setSalary` of the `Manager` class because it's the "runtime type" of `ken`, but it calls the `setSalary` of the `Employee` class. can someone explain what's is going on here thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully at the `setSalary` method in class `Employee`:

```
public void setSalary(double salary)
```

And now look carefully at the `setSalary` method in class `Manager`:

```
public void setSalary(int salary)
```

Do you see the difference? The one in class `Employee` takes a `double`, while the one in class `Manager` takes an `int`.

Therefore, the one in class `Manager` does *not* override the one in class `Employee`.

For a method to override a method from a superclass, it must conform to the following rules:

- The name of the method must be the same
- The number and types of the parameters must be the same

You could have caught this error if you had used the `@Override` annotation in class `Manager`:

```
class Manager extends Employee {
    @Override
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        System.out.println("Manager.setSalary():" + salary);
    }
}
```

By using the `@Override` annotation, you tell the compiler that the method is supposed to override a method from its superclass. If it doesn't, then the compiler will give you an error.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct.

Except that the method `public void setSalary(int salary)` in class `Manager` is not overriding the method `public void setSalary(double salary)`, because `double` and `int` are two different types.

Declare `public void setSalary(double salary)` in the class `Manager` and it will work as you expect.

Little tip: use `@Override` annotation on overridden methods. If you were doing so, you would have spotted the issue right after.